# Why my form is not sending to backend image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vuejs web aplication. In there have a form to edit-user's data. The part of edit the data like 'name', 'phone', etc is working like a charm but when the user come's to the profille picture upload they simply not upload from the backend ( codeigniter4 Rest API ). In the mobile application is everything ok to the update of that. Here is the code:

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" @change="`whenSelectImage" />

  <div class="button" @click.prevent="atualizarUsuario();uploadFoto()">
     <slot>Atualizar informações</slot>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the methods part:

```js
  whenSelectImage(event){
      this.selectedPicture= event.target.files[0]
    },
    uploadFoto(){
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('image', this.selectedPicture, this.selectedPicture.name)
      apiOnline
        .post(
            `/usuario/dados/${window.localStorage.uuid}`, fd
        ).then(res => {
          console.log(res.response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
    }
```

the console says:

"undefined"

and in the Network Headers they are sending Form Data with Image: ( binary )

I'm using Vuex to store the data of the user

Comment: the parsed returns to: 

------WebKitFormBoundaryV9YVBV2UdEpngSks
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryV9YVBV2UdEpngSks--

Comment: are you sure it's not a problem on the backend?